# MySql Leap Years

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table called reviews which stores a lot of product reviews, accumulated over many years, each annotated with a date timestamp.
I wanted to draw a bar-chart showing me the number of reviews I have accumulated on each day of the year, hoping to find the important dates for my system.

I used this query

```
select dayofyear(date),count(*) from reviews group by dayofyear(date);
```

However, after noticing that this is returning 366 rows instead of 365, I have realized that I cannot use this for making this chart, because the day index is getting offset by 1 every leap year, which is skewing my data.

For example, Christmas is showing up as day #359 on most years, but its #360 on leap years.

What is the simplest way to resolve this skew?

On a sidenote, is there any software package that can accept an SQL query and return the results directly as a bar-chart (when a bar-chart makes sense)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you could do something like the following:

```
SELECT 
        # check if the year is a leap year:
        IF((YEAR(mydate) % 4 = 0 AND YEAR(mydate) % 100 != 0) OR YEAR(mydate) % 400 = 0,
            # if so, check if the date is before or after february 29th. if that is the case, we subtract one from the value
            IF(DAYOFYEAR(mydate) > DAYOFYEAR("2008-02-28"), DAYOFYEAR(mydate) - 1, DAYOFYEAR(mydate)),
            # if the year isn't a leap year, just return the regular dayofyear() value
            DAYOFYEAR(mydate))
    FROM mytbl
```

This will merge the data for the 28th and 29th for leap years, but give the same offsets for the days during leap years and non-leap years for all other days. A more desirable behaviour could be to simply ignore the data from february 29th, which could be accomplished using additional conditions. You could also assign it a special index, such as 400, which won't offset all other days.

A better way might be to group by month and day of month:

```
select month(date) m, day(date) d, count(*) from reviews group by m, d;
```

This avoids the problem all together, but might be more complicated for you to process in your application logic. Still, I'd argue that it's a lot better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Group them by day of month, and rinse and repeat for each month?

Answer (score -1):

```
DELIMITER //
   CREATE FUNCTION leap_year (y INT)
      RETURNS INT
  DECLARE income INT;
      IF (y%4 = 0) THEN
        SET income = TRUE;
      ELSE
        SET income = FALSE;
      END IF;
      RETURN income;
  END; // DELIMITER ;
```

The above written code is to find a leap year using function in MySQL Workbench, which I use mostly(workbench). Once you write this code and execute this, you can see the function is create in left side with leap_year in schema.

You need to call this function to see the output of this function.
For calling this function.

```
SELECT leap_year(2023);
```

Once you hit above line and see the output will show you "0", which means 2023 is not a leap year.

I hope you understand this.

Comment: Take some time to read about leap years: https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html